# What is the meaning of "out back" in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "out back" in the sentence, "Somebody quieted the dogs out back" ?

Does it mean "Somebody made the dogs quiet. and somebody took the dogs out again" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Out back** - Outside at the back of a given house or building.

[Source](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/out+back)

Comment: If so, does "Somebody quieted the dogs out back" mean "Somebody quieted the dogs which is outside at the back of a  house" ?

Comment: yes, I believe this is what's being implied here.

Answer (score 1):

In this sentence 'out back' refers to the back yard (the garden at the back of a house)...
The sentence as a whole could mean one of two things... 
It could mean that the dogs were in the back yard barking and somebody went out there to quieten them (calm them down).
OR
It could mean that the dogs were barking and generally making a ruckus inside the house so somebody took them out the back (to the garden) to get them out of the way and calm them down.

Also, as some extra information, the word 'quieted' can mean to make them quiet, but there's more to the meaning of the word than that - To quieten someone or something, is to make them less noisy, less active, or silent. To calm them.